# Please make a pink tag for "canonical questions"

Tags: soporte, petición-de-funcionalidad, etiquetas, preguntas-canónicas, elementos-destacados

Please make a pink tag for "canonical questions" -- for example [Editions of Spanish Orthographies? / ¿Qué revisiones ha tenido la ortografía española?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10328/9385)

---

Also, I apparently need help deleting a tag I regret having created: [historical-document](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-document).

---

Here's a pink tag.  It stands out nicely.

[image: pink tag in question list]

[image: pink tag in question itself]

Comment: Pink tags are hardcoded in the [se] code and are the [status-*] kind, and also [featured], nothing else. Also, I do not see the point of it.

Comment: The tag [tag:historical-document] you mention does not have any question, so it is technically deleted. There is no need to do anything.

Comment: @fedorqui - I see, thanks.   When I deleted the tag from the question I had applied it to, it ended up in the ether.  RIP.  (Rest in Peace.)

Comment: Exactly, they are automatically deleted when no questions use them

Comment: See [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags), from Meta.SE faq.

Comment: I see.  They die a daily batched death.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pink tags are only available in Meta, so a question like [Editions of Spanish Orthographies? / ¿Qué revisiones ha tenido la ortografía española?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10328/1674), that can be found in the main site, cannot have it.

---

Regarding removing a tag [blabla](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blabla), you can get rid of it by removing it from all questions. The system will do the rest automatically: [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/209901)